# Returning an array in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that returns a two-element array value in Google Apps Script.  Apparently I have misunderstood something because I thought that would be a simple matter of specifying:

```
      return [ value1 ][ value2 ]
```

at the end of the function, but that is not working for me.  So as a proof of concept, I wrote the following:

```
function testReturnArray() {
      var theValue = returnArray();
      Logger.log(theValue);
      }

function returnArray() { return ["a"]["b"]; }
```

When I run this code through the debugger, the log written is:

```
6:33:08 PM  Info    null
```

Clearly that's not my intended result.  Can you please point me to the problem?  I really would like to have two values returned from this function, and this is the easiest way I could think to do that.  (Alternative being to return a class, but that may be overkill for my goal, and may also have a similar issue.)

Comment: what about `[value1,value2]` ? or `[[value1],[value2]]` ???

Comment: `function returnArray() { return ["a","b"]; }` or `function returnArray() { return [["a"],["b"]]; }` depending on whether you want an array of elements or an array of arrays.

Comment: Yes, of course you're right.  Silly me, syntax problem.  I appreciate the help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you write arrays in JavaScript. You need to use a comma to separate the values. There's a lot of content explaining arrays, but I'll suggest [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) as one to start with.

```js
var theValue = returnArray();
console.log(theValue);

function returnArray() { return [ "a", "b" ]; }
```